# Book about a man and woman stranded on a moon or asteroid, who have to rebuild or repair their crashed spacecraft

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I remember a book I read in my teen years (the eighties).

A man and woman are stranded together on a moon or asteroid. They have to rebuild or repair their crashed spacecraft. They make all kinds of things from scratch - like forges and maybe a lumbermill kind of things. She is the daughter of someone powerful, and he is not rich. This dynamic adds some drama to a budding romance. By the end of the book, he is dying for a cigarette. I remember that he was so happy when they are rescued, and he gets to smoke.

I only remember two scenes with any clarity. In one scene, he is lying on the ground (maybe beside a lake?) in exhaustion and despair, and she tries to comfort him with words like "You've gone from the stone age to nuclear fusion all by yourself in such a short time. You can't do everything." In the other scene, they've been rescued, he's had his smoke, life is good again, and he is given permission to marry the girl.

It's not the short story "[The Mad Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mad_Moon)" (1935) by Stanley G. Weinbaum, although I think the author was probably influenced by that work.

Comment: Similar setting but not the same book, I recall a story of a kid builds a antigravity drive (in his tree house?) flies it realizes it has flaws so builds a second in a better "ship" and flies it to the Mars. But the drive breaks. His Girlfriend, when he does not return, realizes what he has done and flies his first "ship" (the Treehouse?) to Mars to "rescue him. She passes out just before landing due to lack of oxygen, and crashes. Together they try to survive on Mars... (Probably about a 1960s novel)

Comment: @NJohnny please post that as a question, it rings a faint bell in my memory, I'd love it if someone could answer it so I could get a copy

Comment: @DannyMcG Question posted

Comment: It's Factorio!?

Answer (score 13):

This is almost certainly *Spacehounds of IPC* by E.E. "Doc" Smith.

The protagonists, Percival "Steve" Stevens and Nadia Newton, manage to escape to Ganymede when the passenger liner they're in, *en route* from Earth to Mars, is intercepted, cut up like scrap, and taken in tow by aliens who turn out to be from Jupiter.

On Ganymede (which has an Earthlike atmosphere, but low gravity and hostile natives), Steve builds a complete machine shop to rebuild the *Forlorn Hope* -- a scrap of the main ship with some "accumulators" and a couple "projectors" -- into a usable ship.  He also, as seems sensible, arms it with what weapons he can build from the resources he had (mainly heat rays).  Then, when well out in space in order to evacuate a huge vacuum tube needed to make a transmitter that can reach Earth, they encounter aliens from a moon of Saturn (Titan?  Been about fifty years since I read this), assist them in rebuilding the thermoelectric power system that powers their entire civilization, and in return receive help they'll need to get past the Jovians after contacting Steve's friends back home.

This is pure space opera, and it was very good for 1947.

Comment: Nice. And of course "space opera" was very definitely Doc's style.

Comment: @Zeisse Ikon   Like many old science fiction novels, Spacehounds of IPC was originally published in a pulp magazine and then republished as a book post world War Two.  Spacehounds of IPC was originally published in the 1930s.  As a general rule, a science fiction book which seems very old fashioned was probably first published in a pulp magazine before WWII.

Comment: @M.A.Golding You are surely correct; the overall feel of the story and the somewhat episodic nature fit better as a publication in parts (what we'd now call a "makeup" novel), and a number of the tropes are 1920s-1930s flavored.